# Is it fine to use Savings account to pay salaries? what is the downside?

Tags: united-states, india, salary, savings-account, checking-account

It is taking us time to get checking/current account for the business. We want to know, if it is OK to pay through Business Owner's personal savings account and still have it as a record of business. Basically paying salaries/remunerations for employees/contractors and for paying taxes to government.

Jurisdiction  - India and USA
Type of Business - Private limited / Delaware C Corp

Thanks @Kevin & @Grade'Eh'Bacon for helping me to provide right context

Comment: Do you mean one of the owners' personal savings accounts? Is the business incorporated, or a legal partnership, or similar?

Comment: I'd *loan* the company the money, and then the company would pay you back.  That would keep you from mixing business and personal accounts.

Comment: As you said it's taking time to open current account, till then you are bound to give salary from your personal account